# Estimating the volume of a spherical cap

Tags: probability, geometry

If $d$ is very large, there is a nice way to estimate the surface area of a "spherical cap," that is, the part of a unit $(d-1)$-sphere on one side of a hyperplane: each coordinate of a random point on the surface of the sphere is distributed almost like a Gaussian with variance $1/d$, and we can use this to determine the probability that a random point lies in the cap.

This trick is useful for other questions related to the spherical cap, and so it would be nice to know how good this Gaussian approximation is. Is there a nice bound one can prove in terms of $d$?

The particular quantity I'm trying to estimate is the following: given a spherical cap whose surface area takes up some fraction $\alpha$ of the total surface area of the sphere, what is the average Euclidean distance from a random point on the sphere to the closest point on the cap?

Comment: I need a bound on the estimation of volume of spherical cap using sampling. Do you have any hints?